# not exist clause gives invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem: I am trying to check if record is already available in table or not. For this check I use two columns id and isAlive.

```
Insert into table1 (id,name,isAlive)
  Select t2.id, 
         t2.name, 
         null as isAlive
    From table2 t2
   Where Not exist ( select 1 
                       from table1 t1 
                      where t1.id=t2.id
                        and t1.column2 is null )

Table1 Data:
{id,name,isAlive}
{123,'Test','Y'}
{234,'Test1',null}

Table2 Data:
{id,name}
{123,'Test'}
{234,'Test1'}
{456,'Test2'}
```

When I try to insert 456 in table t1, my sql is failing with below error

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: you are probably trying to insert a varchar2 column into a number column.  You think the varchar column has numbers but it only takes 1 row to get this error

Comment: Query is working fine if I have records containing t1.column2 with null, but gives error if no record found with null

Comment: Please show the COMPLETE AND EXACT error message, and your table schema definition.  We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

one of the column was varchar and I was comparing it with number
Thanks. Resolved